# .isArray not returning a value when expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping over some items in a config file in my component and if an item is an array I want to render each value in the array together. I'm using .isArray to check if an item is an array but it's not returning a value when I expect it to.

Example config

```
items: [
          {
            text: 'some text',
            url: '/some-url.html'
          }, {
            text: 'some text',
            url: '/some-url.html'
          }, [
            {
              text: 'some text',
              url: '/some-url.html'
            },
            {
              text: 'some text',
              url: '/some-url.html'
            }
          ], {
            text: 'some text',
            url: '/some-url.html'
          }
]

    const items = items.filter(item => {
      return item.text !== undefined
    }).map((item, itemKey) => {
      if (item.isArray) return console.log(item);
      return (
        <Item key={key} item={item.url} />
      )
    })
```

I have an array in my items but I am not getting a console.log

Comment: Did you mean `items.isArray()` with parentheses?

Comment: isArray is a method call .isArray()

Comment: Your current implementation will replace non-array elements with `undefined`. It looks like you need to modify your `.filter()` by moving the `isArray()` check. Alternatively, you could flatten the array if you need to include the nested elements in your UI.

Comment: "it's not returning a value when I expect it to." Which line of code do you expect to return a value that isn't returning?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice you were right in your first comment! if i move the console log into the .filter it logs the array item :)

Comment: @user3005003 In your original code, your array items are filtered out because `item.text` is undefined for an array.

Comment: For future reference, https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a great article with some tips about how to debug issues like this. For example, you could have put `console.log(item)` in your original code before `if(item.isArray)` in order to see what items you are mapping over.

Answer (score 4):

`isArray` is a method from Array.

It returns you back **true** or **false** if what you pass within the parenthesis is an array.

```
Array.isArray([1, 2, 3]); // true or false
```

In your case you should check it like this:

```
const items = items.filter(item => {
      return item.text !== undefined
    }).map((item, itemKey) => {
      if (Array.isArray(item)) return console.log(item);
      return (
        <Item key={key} item={item.url} />
      )
    })
```

---

> **DOCS**: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

Comment: thank you for a thorough answer, I have now updated my code but I don't think this is the only problem as it is still not returning a console log

Comment: thank you for a thorough answer, I have now updated my code but I don't think this is the only problem as it is still not returning a console log

Comment: @user3005003 What do you mean by "returning a console log"? What do you expect `return console.log(item)` to do?

Comment: It doesn't console.log anything because when you filter you are checking `item.text !== undefined`. When it goes through the Array, that array doesn't have a property called **text** so it will filter it an the results are always going to be three objects: `[{…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think he just wants to console.log the item in case it's an array. You don't have to return it tho... But as I explained above, he'll never be able to see anything because he's filtering first.

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = items.filter(item => {
      return item.text !== undefined
    }).map((item, itemKey) => {
      if (item.isArray) return console.log(item);
      return (
        <Item key={key} item={item.url} />
      )
    })
```

You have several problems in this code. First of all, `item.isArray` is `undefined` for all values in your array. None of the items has a key `isArray`. To fix this, change it to

```
Array.isArray(item);
```

Next, `console.log(item)` returns `undefined`. This means that even if you make the above change, you will get a list with `undefined` elements in some slots.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        const items = [
                  {
                    text: 'some text',
                    url: '/some-url.html'
                  }, {
                    text: 'some text',
                    url: '/some-url.html'
                  }, [
                    {
                      text: 'some text',
                      url: '/some-url.html'
                    },
                    {
                      text: 'some text',
                      url: '/some-url.html'
                    }
                  ], {
                    text: 'some text',
                    url: '/some-url.html'
                  }
        ]
        
        
        const data = items.filter(item => {
              return item.text !== undefined
            })
        console.log(data) // this line return the following comment
        /*[
          {
            "text": "some text",
            "url": "/some-url.html"
          },
          {
            "text": "some text",
            "url": "/some-url.html"
          },
          {
            "text": "some text",
            "url": "/some-url.html"
          }
        ] */
    
       // So It will never run the if condition in below code because there is no child array in the filtered array.
        data.map((item, itemKey) => {
              if (Array.isArray(item)) return console.log("I'm an array")
              return console.log("I'm not an array")
            })
```